# Video uri is saving null in Firestore

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

Basically the problem is that 'imagedata' is null.I am uploading a video to firebase and saving the download URL in the firestore database. The first time I did it the video URL did show up in firestore but later I made some changed to the code and now it is showing null in the Firestone. It would be amazing if anyone could help me. The video URL is present in storage and stuff.

**My java code**

```
package post;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


import com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView;
import com.example.myapplication.R;
import com.example.myapplication.homepage;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class videopost extends AppCompatActivity {

    private VideoView videoView;
    private final int CODE_ONE_VIDEO = 1;

    ImageView imageView;
    TextView reviewactivity1;
    Button dishvideo;
    Button post;
    FirebaseFirestore fStore;
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;
    String user_id;
    int numberofposts = 1;
    String videouri;
    String titleget;
     String cuisineget;
     String uriget;
     LottieAnimationView lottieAnimationView;

    Uri imagedata;

    private int ImageBack = 1;
    private StorageReference fStorage,fStorage2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_videopost);

        fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        lottieAnimationView = findViewById(R.id.loading3);
        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        fStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Post Images");
        fStorage2 = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Post Videos");

        user_id = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        videoView = findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        post = findViewById(R.id.postrecipe);
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        dishvideo = findViewById(R.id.pickvideo);
        reviewactivity1 = findViewById(R.id.review);

        Intent data = getIntent();
        titleget = data.getStringExtra("title");
         cuisineget = data.getStringExtra("cuisine");
         uriget = data.getStringExtra("imageuri");

      /*  post.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
dishvideo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
post.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        videoView.pause();
                                        lottieAnimationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        lottieAnimationView.playAnimation();
                                        final StorageReference images = fStorage.child(user_id + " post " + numberofposts + " display image.");
                                        images.putFile(Uri.parse(uriget)).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                                final StorageReference videos = fStorage2.child(user_id + " post " + numberofposts + " recipe video ");
                                                videos.putFile(Uri.parse(String.valueOf(imagedata))).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                                        videos.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                                                videouri = String.valueOf(uri);

                                                            }
                                                        });

                                                    }
                                                });
                                                images.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                                        DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("User post data").document(user_id + " post " + numberofposts);
                                                        Map<String, Object> userposts = new HashMap<>();
                                                        userposts.put("imageUrl", String.valueOf(uri));
                                                        userposts.put("Title of dish", titleget);
                                                        userposts.put("Cuisine", cuisineget);
                                                        userposts.put("Video uri", videouri);
                                                        documentReference.set(userposts).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                                                                dishvideo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                                post.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                                lottieAnimationView.pauseAnimation();
                                                                videoView.pause();

                                                                lottieAnimationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                                while(numberofposts <10000) {
                                                                    numberofposts++;
                                                                }
                                                                Toast.makeText(videopost.this, "Recipe posted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), homepage.class));
                                                            }
                                                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                                                lottieAnimationView.pauseAnimation();
                                                                dishvideo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                                post.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                                lottieAnimationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                                videoView.pause();

                                                                Toast.makeText(videopost.this, "Recipe could not be posted.Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                                            }
                                                        });
                                                    }
                                                });


                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                }); */


        imageView = findViewById(R.id.close3);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), homepage.class));
            }
        });

        mediaController.setMediaPlayer(videoView);

        dishvideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(new Intent().setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT).setType("video/mp4"),
                        "Select a video"),
                        CODE_ONE_VIDEO);
            }
        });
    }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult ( int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data){
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == CODE_ONE_VIDEO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                videoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                post.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                 imagedata = data.getData();
                if (imagedata != null) {

                    videoView.setVideoURI(imagedata);
                    videoView.start();



                    reviewactivity1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent review = new Intent(v.getContext(), reviewactivity.class);
                            review.putExtra("title",titleget);
                            review.putExtra("cuisine",cuisineget);
                            review.putExtra("imageuri",uriget);
                            review.putExtra("videouri", imagedata);
                            startActivity(review);


                        }
                    });

                    post.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            dishvideo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            post.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            videoView.pause();
                            lottieAnimationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            lottieAnimationView.playAnimation();
                            final StorageReference images = fStorage.child(user_id + " post " + numberofposts + " display image.");
                            images.putFile(Uri.parse(uriget)).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                     final StorageReference videos = fStorage2.child(user_id + " post " + numberofposts + " recipe video ");
                                    videos.putFile(Uri.parse(String.valueOf(imagedata))).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                            videos.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                                    videouri = String.valueOf(uri);

                                                }
                                            });

                                        }
                                    });
                                    images.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                            DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("User post data").document(user_id + " post " + numberofposts);
                                            Map<String, Object> userposts = new HashMap<>();
                                            userposts.put("imageUrl", String.valueOf(uri));
                                            userposts.put("Title of dish", titleget);
                                            userposts.put("Cuisine", cuisineget);
                                            userposts.put("Video uri", videouri);
                                            documentReference.set(userposts).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                                                    dishvideo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                    post.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                    lottieAnimationView.pauseAnimation();
                                                    videoView.pause();

                                                    lottieAnimationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                    while(numberofposts <10000) {
                                                        numberofposts++;
                                                    }
                                                    Toast.makeText(videopost.this, "Recipe posted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), homepage.class));
                                                }
                                            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                                    lottieAnimationView.pauseAnimation();
                                                    dishvideo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                    post.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                    lottieAnimationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                    videoView.pause();

                                                    Toast.makeText(videopost.this, "Recipe could not be posted.Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                                    });


                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });

                }else{
                    post.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    reviewactivity1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Toast.makeText(videopost.this, "You must select a video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                    post.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Toast.makeText(videopost.this, "You need to select a video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

**My xml code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/postactivityvisibility"
    tools:context="post.videopost">


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/borderbottomgrey"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/close3"
                    android:layout_width="30sp"
                    android:layout_height="30sp"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_close_black_24dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/review"
                    android:layout_width="256dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:text="Review"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="#047cfb"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />



            </LinearLayout>





        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>



    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Pick a recipe video for your dish"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/videoView"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />


    </LinearLayout>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/postrecipe"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="450dp"
        android:background="#047cfb"
        android:text="Post recipe"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pickvideo"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="400dp"
        android:background="#047cfb"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_videocam_black_24dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:text="Pick video"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
            android:id="@+id/loading3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:lottie_loop="true"
            app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/postloading" />


</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**My firestore collection**

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4zg5.png)

Comment: I had one more question to anyone that can help.When I save the post in firebase I use a number after each post and I want that number to increase by 1 after every post.Any idea on how to do that?I want it to be like userid + " post " + thenumber;I have tried but the number is not increased and  a new document is not created.

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted **more than 450 lines of code** for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.